# Cannot test input type datetime-local with Larave Dusk

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-dusk

I have following code in my form. I need to let user input date and time.

```php
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="collection_datetime" name="collection_datetime" required>
```

When trying to automatically test form with Laravel Dusk I will always get an error.

[image: form error]

This is what I tried this

```php
 ->type('collection_datetime', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i'))
->type('collection_datetime', '12/31/2019 12:59 PM')
```

non of it worked.
Any suggestion you can give me is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked, I hope it will help someone.
It seems to me non-trivial I hope there is prettier solution

```php
                ->type('collection_datetime', '13')
                ->type('collection_datetime', 'sep')
                ->keys('#collection_datetime', ['{tab}'])
                ->type('collection_datetime', '2019')
                ->keys('#collection_datetime', ['{tab}'])
                ->type('collection_datetime', '0104AM')
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting datetime-local input using javascript in Laravel Dusk:

```
$browser->script('
var dateString = "10/4/22 7:9:00 PM"
    if (dateString !== "") {

        var dateVal = new Date(dateString);
        var day = dateVal.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var month = (1 + dateVal.getMonth()).toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var hour = dateVal.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var minute = dateVal.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var sec = dateVal.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var ms = dateVal.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, "0");
        var inputDate = dateVal.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day) + "T" + (hour) + ":" + (minute);

        $("#deadline").val(inputDate);
    }
');
```